# Обновление данных chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

Есть функция рисования графика использующая chart.js. По оси x расположены даты, для этого используется moment.js. Хочу написать функцию обновляющую график. Данные по оси y обновляются без проблем, но данные по оси x - нет. Не изменяются максимальная и минимальная даты. Выдает ошибку.

```
 var mainChart;
function draw(type, title, start_date, end_date) {
    function arrayFill(values, consumed_values) {
        for (var i = 0; i < consumed_values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = consumed_values[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    var date = new Array;
    var i = 0;
    date[i] = new Date(moment(start_date).add(1, 'days'));
    do {
        date[i + 1] = new Date(moment(date[i]).add(1, 'days'));
        i++;
    } while (date[i] < end_date);
    var values = new Array;
    arrayFill(values, document.querySelectorAll('ul.values.' + type + ' li'));
    var resultData = {
        labels: date,
        datasets: [{
            label: title,
            fontSize: 18,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(184,202,222,0.9)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(37,78,136, 1)',
            data: values
        }]
    };
    var options = {
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 1000,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Расход',
                    fontSize: 17
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    min: start_date,
                    max: end_date
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: title,
            fontSize: 19
        }
    };
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas#canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    mainChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: resultData,
        options: options
    });
}

function redraw() {
    var value = document.getElementById('time_calendar').value;
    var new_start_date = value.slice(0,8);
    new_start_date = new Date(moment(new_start_date, 'DD.MM.YY'));
    var new_end_date = value.slice(10);
    new_end_date = new Date(moment(new_end_date, 'DD.MM.YY'));
    var new_date = new Array;
    var i = 0;
    new_date[i] = new Date(moment(new_start_date).add(1, 'days'));
    do {
        new_date[i + 1] = new Date(moment(new_date[i]).add(1, 'days'));
        i++;
    } while (new_date[i] < new_end_date);

    console.log(new_start_date); //дата выводится нормально
    console.log(new_end_date);  //дата выводится нормально
    mainChart.data.labels = new_date;  //работает
    mainChart.options.scales.xAxes.time.min = new_start_date;  //не работает
    mainChart.options.scales.xAxes.time.max = new_end_date;  //не работает
    mainChart.update();
}
```

Как изменить максимальную и минимальную даты корректно?

Comment: `Данные по оси y обновляются без проблем, но данные по оси y - нет.` . по какой оси-то в итоге? И какая ошибка?

Comment: По y - все хорошо, по x - не обновляются максимальная и минимальная даты.